Sum of squares via binomial coefficients, per Knuth
I read Donald E. Knuth' book and have some problem with understanding some topics. He writes: $1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2$ is easy to count if you know that $k^2 = 2 \binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}$. And I totally don't understand why $k^2$ can be represented this way (with combination). I will be thankful for any kind of help to understand logic of this sequence.
P.S. I thought it something related to Pascal's triangle or Stirling numbers, but in vain

Or Kedar has already given an intuitive explanation based on the definition of $k\choose i$ as the number of ways to choose $i$ items from a set of $k$. But in a comment you said

if I want to represent $^3$ it becomes much harder

It's actually straightforward, and for $k^3$ not even difficult.  There is some algebra, but it is all routine.
We want to find numbers $a, b, c$ for which $$k^3 = a{k\choose 3} + b{k\choose 2} + c\binom k1.$$
It happens that $\binom ki$ is always a polynomial in $k$, with degree $i$.  If you expand these (do you know how to do this?) you will have a sum of polynomials on the right:
$$\begin{align} k^3&  = a\left(\frac{k^3-3k^2+2k}6\right)
+ b\left(\frac{k^2-k}2\right)
+ ck \\
& = a\left(\frac16 k^3 - \frac12 k^2 + \frac13 k\right) 
+ b\left(\frac12 k^2 - \frac12 k\right) 
+ ck
\end{align}
$$
Now combine like terms on the right:
$$k^3 = \frac a6  k^3 +
\left(-\frac12 a + \frac12 b\right)k^2 + 
\left(\frac13a -\frac12b +c\right)k.$$
Since we want the two polynomials to be equal, we must require that the corresponding coefficients be equal:
$$\begin{align}
1 & = \frac a6 \\
0 & = -\frac 12 a + \frac12 b \\
0 & = \frac13a -\frac12b +c
\end{align}
$$
We have three equations in three variables, and these are particularly easy to solve.  We get $$a=6,\\ b=6,\\ c=1,$$ so the answer is:
$$k^3 = 6{k\choose 3} + 6{k\choose 2} + \binom k1.$$
(There's also a way to get this that is analogous to Or Kedar's counting method, but I thought you might want to see this somewhat simpler and entirely mechanical method.)
You can do the $k^2$ case for practice and see that you get $a=2, b=1$ as Knuth says.

Here's a combinatorial explanation. Let's say you want to pick an ordered pair (repetitions allowed) from a set $S$ of size $k$.
On one hand, there are $k^2$ such options. On the other hand, you can do this in the following manner:

Decide whether you pick equal elements or two distinct elements.
In the first case, pick an element $i\in S$ and consider the choice $(i,i)$. There are ${k\choose 1}$ such elements.
In the second case, pick an unordered pair $\{a,b\}\subset S, a\neq b$, and order it $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$. There are ${k\choose 2}\cdot 2$ ways to do this.

Since these options exhaust all the ways to pick a pair, we get
$$k^2=2{k\choose 2}+{k\choose 1}$$

I don't know if you want a geometric or deep explanation but $k^2= 2 {{k}\choose{2}}+{{k}\choose{1}}$ is clearly true if you know the definition of the cominatorics.
$${{n}\choose{k}}= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$
Therefore if you calculate:
$$2\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!} + \frac{n!}{(n-1)!1!} = 2\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n = n^2+n-n= n^2 $$

That's not the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$. The definition is "the numbers of the subsets of size $k$ taken from a set of size $n$".

Yes, you're absolutely right. It's easy to understand why this sum of combination is equal to $k^2$, but I don't understand how to represent $k^2$ as sum of combination. That's not a problem with second power, but if I want to represent $k^3$ it becomes much harder.
